# Circular Reference with python lists

Tags: python, list, circular-reference

Can someone explain this?

```
>>> x = x[0] = [0]
>>> x
[[...]]
>>> x is x[0]
True
>>> x[0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[[...]]
>>> x in x
True
```

what is `[...]`?

Comment: FWIW, `x = x[0] = [0]` is confusing. It'd be clearer to do `x = []; x.append(x)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's just Python telling you that you have a circular reference; it's smart enough not to enter an infinite loop trying to print it out.

Answer (score 4):

iPython will do this:

`[<Recursion on list with id=38505216>]`

It's the same thing; the interpreter telling you that you have a recursive data structure.

Answer (score 3):

It's output by the method responsible for generating the representation of the structure. It represents a recursive structure, elided since it can be nested infinitely.