# What is the difference between list[1] and list[1:] in Python?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

```
>>> c=[1,2,3]
>>> c[1]=c 
>>> d=[1,2,3]
>>> d[1:]=d

>>> print(c)
[1, [...], 3] # Why does C become [1, [...], 3]?
>>> print(d)
[1, 1, 2, 3] # Why is d not [1, [...] ]?
```

Excuse me, where is the code different? Is it the `:`, or something else?

Comment: Why do you nest a list inside itself?

Answer (score 11):

You are using an index and a slice assignment, which are quite different.

Compare this with indexing and slicing the list in an expression:

```
>>> c=[1,2,3]
>>> c[1]
2
>>> d=[1,2,3]
>>> d[1:]
[2, 3]
```

By using a `:` colon in the list index, you are asking for a slice, which is always another list.

In Python you can assign values to both an individual item in a list, and to a slice of the list.

Answer (score 3):

`slicing` is used to extract a `sublist` of a list where as `indexing` is used to retrive a specific element of list

`slicedList = aList[beginIndex:endIndex]`

`d[1:]` refers to slicing the list `d` - refer to [this](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python%3aBasics%3aSlices). - This is slicing

`c[1]` is an element of the list `c`. - this is indexing

Answer (score 1):

> print(c) [1, [...], 3] # Why does C become [1, [...], 3]?

When you are doing c[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196329/circular-reference-with-python-lists) = c, you are assigning c itself to the second position of c. This way you are creating cyclic reference.So instead of showing again the list, interprepreter showing [...] to indicate its cyclic reference. [See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196329/circular-reference-with-python-lists)